# Linq with a Dictionary inside the class

Tags: c#, linq

i have the next class:

```
public class Example 
{
    String name;
    Dictionary<String, decimal> data;

    public Example() 
    { 
        data = new Dictionary<String, decimal>();
    }
}
```

Then, using Linq i need to retrieve all distinct String keys in the data field.
For example:

e1: 1 - [["a", 2m],["b",3m])

e2: 2 - [["b", 2m],["c",3m])

I'll need a list with: ["a","b","c"]

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks.

PD: One thing i was missing, i have a List of Examples.

Comment: It's not really clear. Do you have two instances of `Example` then? Does `Example` make the dictionary accessible in some way? Or is this code within the `Example` class? It would really help if you could give a short but *complete* example of what you're trying to do, with just the bit you don't know about missing.

Comment: Hi Jon, i'm showing 2 example to clarify the idea, i've really have thousands of instances.

Comment: But my point is that you've got a collection of `Example` instances, and you want a single set of strings across those? Your question really isn't clear at the moment, which is why I've suggested a short but complete program.

Comment: Yes, i want a single set of strings (key of the inner dictionary).

Comment: Right - now you're still not showing how any code can *get* to the dictionary, given that it's private... Once more: a short but complete example would really help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean you have a collection of Examples (e1, e2...):

```
var keys = examples.SelectMany(example => example.data.Keys)
                   .Distinct();
```

Comment: @Rob - not across several dictionaries.

Comment: @RobertLevy In one single dictionary yes but I understood he had a collection of instances each of which having its own dictionary ( maybe I misunderstood...)

Comment: One thing, the predicate must be: (example => example.Data.Keys). Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel Good point, to be even pickier, it must be example.data.Keys, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = 
    (from ex in examples
     from key in ex.Data.Keys
     select key).Distinct();
```